# Is Lenovo Z50-70 compatible with Ubuntu?

Tags: lenovo

I am thinking about buying a Lenovo Z50-70 i7 laptop. It comes with DOS and I am planning to install Ubuntu (Actually, I am planning for Ubuntu/winodws 7 dual boot). However I did not find it in this database of Ubuntu certified hardware: http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/desktop/

I have also found some posts in this and other forums by people having some issues with Ubuntu on this laptop. My question is, should I go for the laptop or better look for another one with pre-installed Ubuntu? Anyone out there has this laptop, installed Ubuntu successfully and things are going smooth without any major issues?

Comment: Here is a list of hardware suppliers all around the world that offer Ubuntu or other distros pre-installed. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuPre-installed

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because hardware recommendation questions are off-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your Bios first. change 'Boot Mode[UEFI] ' to 'Legacy Support'  and install windows create 3 partitions and make one unallocated once the installation of windows completed just try to install UBUNTU.
yes you are right in Lenovo Z50-70  there are so many problem like Realtek,Graphics and WiFi Etc;  but you can solve those issues very easily 
sorry for my bad English becouse is not my primary language :)

Comment: "but you can solve those issues very easily", any reference on how to solve those issues ("problem like Realtek,Graphics and WiFi Etc")?